# Cypress - Comparing element text within an array loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, cypress

I have a page with card elements, and more cards are loaded as the user scrolls down. I am trying to write a test to scroll down until all the card elements are loaded.

What I am trying:

1. Get the text of the last card on the page (lastCard)
2. Scroll down
3. Get the text of the last card that just loaded (currentCard)
4. If both cards have the same text, then end the loop. Repeat if not.

```
let stopScroll
let currentCard
let lastCard
let scrollArray = Array.from({length:100},(v,k)=>k+1)
    cy.wrap(scrollArray).each((index) => {
            if (stopScroll != true) {
                cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().then(($element) => {
                    lastCard = $element.text();
                })
                cy.get('[data-testid="footer"]').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible')
                cy.wait(1000)
                cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().then(($element) => {
                    currentCard = $element.text();
                    if (lastCard == currentCard){
                        stopScroll = true
                        cy.log(stopScroll)
                        }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    if (stopScroll == true){
                    return false
                }
              })
            }
        })
```

The loop keeps going on even though stopScroll is being set to true.
Everything seems to work up to the point of ".then(()". I am unsure whether this is the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do it by doing the `if (stopScroll != true)` check inside a `cy.then()` callback

```js
let stopScroll = false;
cy.wrap(scrollArray).each((index) => {
  cy.then(() => {
    if (stopScroll != true) {
      cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().invoke('text').as('card1')
      cy.get('[data-testid="footer"]').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible')
      cy.wait(1000)
      cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().invoke('text').as('card2')

      cy.get('@card1').then(card1 => {
        cy.get('@card2').then(card2 => {
          if (card1 !== card2) {
            stopScroll = true
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
```

The reason is that `stopScroll = true` only happens inside a `.then()`, which means it's occurring on the Cypress queue. To make the `if()` check work, you also need that to be on the Cypress queue - that is, inside another `.then()`.

---

But Cypress might be touchy about nesting too many commands. If you get an error, try an alternate pattern using a function which calls itself until the condition is met.

```js
function compareCards(counter = 0) {

  if (counter > 20) then throw new Error('Too many loops')

  cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().invoke('text').as('card1')
  cy.get('[data-testid="footer"]').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible')
  cy.wait(1000)
  cy.get('[data-testid="card"]').last().invoke('text').as('card2')

  cy.get('@card1').then(card1 => {
    cy.get('@card2').then(card2 => {
      if (card1 !== card2) {
        compareCards(++counter)
      }
    })
  })
}
compareCards()
```

The `counter` is added to make sure it does not run infinitely (in case the cards never match). You can increase the counter limit to suit your test.